# find string values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have nearly 200+variables and ~2M records in **Pandas dataframe**. All variables should contain numeric data. But due to some error all the variables having some random text inside. I don't know what are those text and all the variables not having same kind of text.

I want to extract those string in variable wise.

Ex:
**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filter by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
out = df.melt().loc[lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x['value'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```

---

```
out = df.melt()
out = out[pd.to_numeric(x['value'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```